# How to add multiple objects types in the same list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Am new in java and try to get over it. I have data like (`String URL, int Score`) and i want to implement it in Array List. I've searched about how to implement multiple type of variable in `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` and found that the solution is to create sub class from super class and i create this sub class:

```
public class MySubClass extends MyList{

public String URL;
public int UrlScore;

public MySubClass (String a, int b){

    URL = a;
    UrlScore = b;
    }
}
```

And my super class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList <MySubClass> myList_1 = new ArrayList <MySubClass> ();

    myList_1.add("http://www.something.com", 5);

    System.out.println(myList_1);   

    }
}
```

I've got error when i try to use Add `Add` object ? The error said:

> The method add(int, MySubClass) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Can you tell me please where am doing the wrong ? And how can i fixed it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myList.add(new MySubClass("...", 5));` perhaps?

Comment: its works now thank you. But the out put is something like
MySubClass@15db9742

it should be print this line:
"http://www.something.com", 5 

Do you know what am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it via creating object of MySubClass and adding it to the list E.g.

```
MySubClass obj = new MySubClass("http://www.something.com", 5);
myList_1.add(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks its works now but when i compiled it i've got something like this: 
MySubClass@15db9742

Can you tell me why it is not printing ("http://www.something.com", 5) ?

Comment: @medo0070 override `toString` method in `MySubClass` class. Also, from your current code, there's no need for `MySubClass` to extend `MyList` class.

Comment: You need to override the `toString` method in MySubClass e.g.   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MySubClass{" +
                "URL='" + URL + '\'' +
                ", UrlScore=" + UrlScore +
                '}';
    }

Comment: But is method `toString` will convert `int Score, String URL` to both `String` ? I do not want to convert my `int Score` to `String` since i will use it to compare with other URLs's Score and add them to the `PriorityQueue`. My question is method `toString` will convert other data types (`int, float, double`) to `String` or its just a way to deal with mixed (data type) cases ? Thanks

Comment: @medo0070 When you call `System.out.println(someObj)` then java invokes `toString` method to display  object information. You are free to display all the relevant information that you are interested to see, it has no impact on Priority queue or anything else.

Comment: @sol4me thank you for your answer .. So my `int`variable will not **convert its type to String** am i wrong ? :)

Comment: @medo0070 No your int variable will not convert its type to String

Comment: @medo0070 Glad it helps, remember you can always mark the answer which you found useful as accepted.

Comment: Thank your very much @sol4me. I know that but since am new here i don't have much points to get vote :(

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to add an instance of `MySubClass` to the list :

```
myList.add(new MySubClass("http://www.something.com", 5));
```

BTW, there is no need for `MySubClass` to be a sub-class of `MyList`.

As mentioned in the comments, you should override the `toString()` method in your `MySubClass` in order to display each instance of `MySubClass` as you wish.

A possible implementation :

```
public class MySubClass 
{

    public String URL;
    public int UrlScore;

    public MySubClass (String a, int b)
    {
        URL = a;
        UrlScore = b;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return URL + "=" + UrlScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you suggest me how to do the code better way in your point view ? Thanks in advance.

BTW: i tried your method and compiled it without error but the output is something like this: 

MySubClass@15db9742

Can you tell me why it is not printing ("http://www.something.com", 5) ? Thanks again @Eran

Comment: Thank you @Eran 
Should i use `Override` method with the code you provided or its not necessary ?

Comment: @medo0070 It's always good to use the `@Override` annotation when overriding a method, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for your advice .. But why i don't use `subClass` ? what should i change it to normal `class` ? What is the matter if i used it ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @medo0070 Based on the code you've shown, there is no need to make MySubClass a sub-class of MyList. MySubClass should extend MyList only if MySubClass is a kind of MyList. Since your MyList class has only a static method (main), I don't see the point in any class extending it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList <MySubClass> myList_1 = new ArrayList <MySubClass> ();
    MySubClass myobj = new MySubClass("http://www.something.com", 5);

    myList_1.add(myobj);



    }
}
```

Try something like that and the code will work.